# Facebook Login with PhoneGap/Cordova App

Tags: facebook, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I recently integrated the phonegap-facebook-plugin (https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin) into both iOS and Android (same app).

I want to do something that I believe to be simple: by-pass the call to native facebook for login/authentication and **always use the web dialog**. How does one go about accomplishing this?

My login code currently looks like this:

Init code:

```
//facebook initialization
FB.init({
    appId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx', //'<%#= FB_APP_ID %>',//'',
    nativeInterface: CDV.FB,
    useCachedDialogs: false
});
```

And the login call is:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
                            if (response.authResponse) {
                                // connected

                                    me.signInFacebook({
                                    token: response.authResponse.accessToken,
                                    email: response.authResponse.email,
                                    success: function (data) {

                                    // hide login view and show tabview
                                     form.destroy();

                                   // continue whatever action was previously happening
                                        me.continueAction(tabIndexBack, callback);
                                    },
                                    failure: function (response) {
                                        // show errors                                      Ext.Viewport.down('tabscontainerview').setActiveItem(3);
                                    }
                                });
                            } else {
                                 //go back
                                Ext.Viewport.down('tabscontainerview').setActiveItem(3);
                                alert('fb login error');
                            }
                        },{ scope: "email" });
```

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: I just want to accomplish the same! any help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16576977/is-there-any-facebook-plugin-for-phonegap-2-7-0/16579592#16579592

Answer (score 4):

I created a plugin to facilitate the connection between Facebook and phonegap without using Plugin Native only with Jquery:

https://github.com/studiosoton/faceGap

Comment: You plugin looks extremely useful! However, I don't understand how to use it. The current javascript is a self contained function, no?

Comment: I used this plugin able to login to facebook. But How to set host for Phonegap projects

Comment: the official one is now [here](https://github.com/wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin)

Answer (score 1):

To bypass native FB login, you can make your own manual facebook authentication flow without using JavaScript SDK of the Facebook (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.3) via inAppBrowser or ChildBrowser plugins.

Your app must initiate a redirect to an endpoint which will display the login dialog:

```
 https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id={app-id}&redirect_uri={redirect-uri}&response_type=token&scope=email
```

Facebook redirects people to the redirect_uri mentioned above and places an access token along with some other metadata (such as token expiry time) in the URI fragment:

```
https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html#
access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN...
```

Your app needs to detect this redirect and then read the access token out of the URI. You can then skip straight to the Inspecting access tokens step.

Answer (score 0):

On the Android version of the plugin, you can force it to use the dialog by modifying the way  the plugin calls `me.facebook.authorize` in the `login` action of the`org.apache.cordova.facebook.ConnectPlugin` class.

You'll need to pass in an additional `activityCode` parameter with [`Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/androidsdk/authentication/):

```
me.facebook.authorize(cordova.getActivity(), me.permissions, Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH, new AuthorizeListener(me));
```

---

I'm not entirely sure about iOS, but you might be able to try with [`openWithBehavior`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBSession#openWithBehavior%3acompletionHandler%3a) and [`FBSessionLoginBehaviorForcingWebView`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBSession#FBSessionLoginBehavior+enum)

Answer (score 0):

Without any Facebook plugins you can use Facebook functionality,for that use **phonegap.facebook.inappbrowser.js** using this js you can easily access all Facebook functionality for more information visit this URL : [Facebook Integration Step without any plugins](https://github.com/caiovaccaro/phonegap.facebook.inappbrowser)